# Website Not Displaying in Firefox, IE or Chrome

Tags: html

I'm using an FTP, and added some simple code to a website. On my desktop within this server, I can't view the content. I've tried Firefox, IE and Chrome. On my phone I can, and tech support could also view the content. I've cleared all cached data, but still nothing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

When I type in www.site.com/index.htm, the content will display on the desktop. When I just type in www.site.com, it won't. When I type in www.site.com on my phone, it will display.

This is the code displaying on my site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<title>Milani Reviews</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>fasdfaskl</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the response status from the server (on the network monitor), when you access using `www.site.com`?

Comment: Response is a blank, white page on the network monitor. 200 OK

Comment: Is it running on `IIS`? If so, check for the default document setting.

Comment: what error you find what's your website address

Comment: Is it the problem only in the mentioned three browsers and not in other browsers like Opera, Safari...?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. After a bit of messing around, I found the problem seemed to be the doctype declaration. I changed it to xml transitional and it displayed the content.

Comment: Your original document looks fine. I doubt if changing the doctype declaration is what actually fixed the problem. If you change it back, does the problem come back? Try changing the page content and see if the new content is visible on your phone with-and-without the index.htm part. Using FTP to browse on the server, are there any other typical default documents? i.e. index.html, default.htm, index.php etc. You can also bypass all caching by trying www.site.com?xyz on your desktop. It will bring up the same page as www.site.com but since the url is different, it won't come from cache.

Comment: I'll definitely look into this. The documents I see on the server are typically index.html. Looks like there's only one other active site on the server though.